# What is exadata database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, oracle-12c, exadata

I need to know Is oracle exadata database is same as the oracle database which is installed in my laptop. What is the main difference.
Can I simply take backup from exadata database and restore it in my laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Exadata database machine is a hardware solution from Oracle which runs the usual Oracle Database Software. However it has an extension: the disks are accessed by special storage nodes which are smart: when the DB tells them to read blocks from a database table they can also tell them filter conditions: the result is that IO bandwidth and caches are distributed to multiple machines and table scans are parallelized (offloading from the main database machine). Besides that there can be additional Flash Cache and the interconnect use fast Infiniband network connections.

This makes it not only faster for typical OLAP queries, but also more robust against wild ad-hoc queries. The disadvantage is that you need to have a big workload so it is worth it.

Exadata uses Linux or Solaris as the Operating System.

It must not be confused with ODA, which is the database appliance without the special storage nodes.

Exadata is for the purpose of applications interacting with it invisible. This also means you can import backups from there and run the same queries (sans management queries for the distributed storage of course).

Comment: So there is no extra effort involved to import backup from exadata machine like when we migrate cross platform databases, we performed extra effort on it.

Comment: Can we create data guard between exadata machine and usual machine for example laptop?

Comment: @Azeem yes. Oracle Exadata is platform like your laptop is a platform. They are both platforms to run Oracle Database. The same Oracle Database binaries are running on both. The same tools and technologies apply. (dg,gg,datapump,etc..)

Comment: @Azeem That is not entirely true. If the primary database on Exadata uses HCC (Hybrid Columnar Compression), a feature specific to Exadata storage and a few other certified storage solutions, you need to do more than just copy it to a third party storage or laptop. You will need to decompress the data. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/availability/maa-wp-dr-dbm-130065.pdf

Comment: @Balazs Papp, oracle introduced the feature in-memory in 12c. It use to handle columnar data, also use the compress and no compress functions. Should I have to decompress tables in 12c?

Comment: @Azeem The In-Memory Column Store, as the name suggests, stores data in columnar formant in memory. HCC stores data compressed on the storage. That is different, so no, you do not need to decompress the data with IM.

Comment: I have no experience with HCC, but if you dont want to risk backup incompatibilities, you dont have to use it. I would however expect that exporting with datapump or logical dataguard standbys are not affected.

Comment: @eckes,Exadata supports Choice of OS is Oracle Linux or solaris 11.